# What calendar integration is possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a client who would like the app we are building to show events from the user's calendar (ICal, Google Cal, etc).  What types of integration is possible from iPhone SDK?

I've only seen NSCalendar so far, which is more of a calendar calculation engine it seems.

Not familiar with calendar APIs in general, so would really appreciate some pointers for starting point of where to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on non-Jailbroken phones, there's no way to access calendar data. File a bug with Apple on this, and perhaps it will be addressed in OS 4!

Comment: How does one file a bug with Apple?  I hear that suggested a lot!

Comment: Go to Apple's bug report website (http://bugreport.apple.com). You'll need to log in with your Apple ID.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 4.0 and beyond, a full integration with the default Calendar is possible. There are already quite a few apps that implement this integration, for instance [Calendar At-A-Glance](http://bit.ly/cJq4Bh). This also allows to be integrated with Google Cal, Microsoft Exchange and all other types of calendars that can be configured to sync with the default calendar. For more details on how to implement it in your app, please see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765).